# I cannot get the expected results when modifying values in a txt.file

Tags: python

Hi guys I'm trying to modify some values in a file by the numbers I want.
The thing is that a rare value is being inserted in the last value added.
I have debugged but I still don't understand how to fix it.
I have a file with numbers from 1 to 10 I want to change them by other numbers that I pass by function that increases by +1.

```
import re
import glob
import os

filename="myfile.txt"
                    
num = 9
def number():
    global num
    num += 1
    return str(num)

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
            
    #1 to 10        
    contents = re.sub(r'^1', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^2', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^3', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^4', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^5', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^6', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^7', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^8', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^9', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    contents = re.sub(r'^10', str(number()), contents, flags = re.MULTILINE)

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(contents)
```

`myfile.txt`  these are the numbers it contains

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
```

`myfile.txt`  the numbers I expect

```
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
```

`myfile.txt`  the numbers I get

```
 19
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 190
```

Comment: In 1 there should be 10 and in 190 there should be 19.

Comment: are your numbers 1:10 column-wise or row-wise inserted initially?

Comment: ^1 also matches the 10 line. And after it is replaced with 10 that first line will match the ^10.  You’ll see the problem if you print contents after each re.sub.

Comment: why not approach the problem numeric?

Comment: the numbers are inserted in columns

Comment: seperated by spaces?

Comment: The cause is already mentioned, but why not print out `contents` for each step along the way. That makes it easier to see where and when things go wrong.

Comment: then it does not take the complete value but it takes the first value and it coincides with r'^1 and r'^10 how can I solve it?

Comment: I think you'd have better luck if you work with the file line by line instead of reading it all at once.

Comment: Does the file have one number per line or is there just one line with multiple values?

Comment: @CtrlZ It's one per line. They didn't use code markup so SO did line folding. I fixed it for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution using strings.   We can use the pythonic way of getting the next line using for in file_object and re.sub our number() value with the digits on that line.

This allows our myfile.txt to be of the following format

```
1. test
2. test 2
3. test 4
```

and be output as

```
10. test
11. test 2
12. test 4
```

Of course the other text is purely optional so your original output will still match as well.

```
import re
import glob
import os

filename = "myfile.txt"

num = 9


def number():
    global num
    num += 1
    return str(num)


contents = ""
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for contents_line in f:
        if re.match('^\d+', contents_line):
            contents_line = re.sub('^\d+', number(), contents_line)
        contents += contents_line
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(contents)
```

Comment: Hi Ted thank you so much for your great contribution, it's amazing it works just as I expected and it's laid out in a better way I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The following describes your desired result in a simple numeric solution:

```py
filename = "myfile.txt"

NUMBER = 9

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    new_string = "\n".join([str(int(val) + NUMBER) for val in content])

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(new_string)
```

If your Problem is numerical solvable and you know that you should give it a try. It would be mostly faster than string shenanigans and in this case it is also easier to understand.

Comment: The numbers should be separated by newline, not space. They didn't format the question properly.

Comment: he mentioned column-wise. Question not very accurate. But I see he updated.

Comment: It's a single column. He didn't know how to use markdown properly to show it.

Comment: yeah got it. update soon.

Comment: he's never adding number() - he seems to be simply using it as a counter from 9

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to add 9 to every integer value found on each line and modify the file accordingly.

If that's the case then the *re* approach is probably not best suited to this problem.

How about:

```
filename = "myfile.txt"

ADD = lambda x: str(int(x) + 9)

with open(filename, "r+") as data:
    nums = data.readlines()
    data.seek(0)
    print(*map(ADD, nums), sep="\n", file=data)
    # truncate is only really necessary if any of the source values are negative
    # it's benign otherwise
    data.truncate()
```

Comment: The examples that you put are working well but I want to do it just in the way in which my question is posed because what I want is to indicate that in the first row of each column the number that I indicate should be changed by the desired number.
I still need help, to modify my code and to achieve it.

Comment: @Maiinjoon my solution will allow you to do both